# I mistakenly deleted /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: mac, dns

I had some issues while running some code and I edited `/etc/resolv.conf`. I experimented with a lot of stuff and ended up with a case where my browsers where not working. I deleted `/etc/resolv.conf` after following chatgpt's instruction. Now I just fixed the issue by using apple's official way of updating dns resolvers which edited `/var/run/resolv.conf`. This change did not update the new `/etc/resolv.conf` that I created.
I want my `/etc/resolv.conf` to be restored to normal.

How do I do this

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/resolv.conf` is just a symlink to `/var/run/resolv.conf`. You can recreate it by running

```
cd /etc
sudo ln -fs ../var/run/resolv.conf .
```

Answer (score -1):

Just copy and paste what you have from `/var/run/resolv.conf` into `/etc/resolv.conf`. Otherwise you can just delete /etc/resolv.conf and wait for your mac to update it itself because I am pretty sure its just a symlink.

Comment: On my Mac (macOs 13.4) `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/var/run/resolv.conf`. So just need to recreate the symlink, then it will be as normal.  Don't copy and paste.